# Как работает передача параметров в post методе с# ASP.NET Core angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть сервис в задачи которого входит идентификация пользователя.

```
export class AuthService {
login: string = "";
password: string = "";
authUser: AuthUser;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

logIn(login: string, password: string): void{
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.authotization()
}

private authotization() {
    var body = { login: "" + this.login, password: "" + this.password };
    return this.http.post("account/login", body);
}
}
```

Тут есть метод и он работает и нормально передает параметры на сервер

```
private authotization() {
    var body = { login: "" + this.login, password: "" + this.password };
    return this.http.post("account/login", body);}
```

Внимание вопрос. Почему не работает следующая версия этого метода?

```
private authotization() {
    var body = { login: this.login, password: this.password };
    return this.http.post("account/login", body);}
```

Я новичок в этом. Я потратил 2 дня на поиски ответа, но он так и остался для меня чем-то магическим

Comment: PS: под не работает я имею ввиду, что он передает пустые значения. Во время запроса на сервере эти параметры равны null

Comment: начнем с того, что без `subscribe` запрос вообще не отправиться. Как он отправляеться с null? Да и путь странный, вы хостите ангуляр на асп вместе с апи?

Comment: Я здесь просто не дописал метод subscribe, я его применяю. Да я использую Angular с ASP.NET Core Web API. Запрос работает нормально и уходит на сервер. Но если в body указать параметры как login = this.login, то на сервере эти параметры равны null, а если login = "" + this.login, то все нормально и они равны тому же чему и были равны на клиентской части

Comment: То, что вы описали, очень маловероятно. Скорее всего у вас где-то в другм месте ошибка... Ну  или единственные вариант - `login` и `password` во втором варианте у вас типа Number. Поэтому, возможно, сервер ожидает, что там будет String и соответственно не берет эти парамерты.

Comment: Ну там точно не число. Функция alert выводит полноценные слова, да и я тут явно задаю тип переменной string. Как переменной класса так и той что подаётся на вход. Но это действительно частный случай. В других запроса к серверу такого не происходит. Ну это я ради интереса спросил. Работающий метод все отрабатывает правильно, так что проблема чисто ради интереса описана